# jQuery menu toggle onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working on a menu with a dropdown on click.

But as you can see from the JsFiddle any links out of the most inner UL do not work.

Here is my javascript I am using:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul > .cat-item").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("ul").show();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/d3p121mc/

Any push in the right direction would be very helpful.

Than you in advance.

Comment: you have only single inner `ul` at Residential. And its working in fiddle. can you please confirm the issue?

Comment: For example the "All" link desn't work.

Comment: but All dont have any inner `ul`

Comment: No but it has a hyper link, which should be opened when the link is clicked.
I know this will work if I remove event.preventDefault(); it will work but then the Residential will not open with a sub menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the JS to the following:-

```
$("section > ul > li > a").click(function () {
    $('ul.children').not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
    $(this).siblings("ul.children").slideToggle();
});
$("section > ul > li").click(function(e){
    if($(this).find('.children').length > 0){
         e.preventDefault();  
    }
});
$("section > ul > li > .children > li > a").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

If there is a better way please let me know?